# asp.net mvc websecurity modify duration of persistCookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies

In my website, I use Websecurity for authentication.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(username, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
    if (Toolbox.IsReturnUrlValid(returnUrl))            
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);                    
    else                    
        return RedirectToLocal("/Profil/Member");
}
```

I want to know how can i set persistCookie duration. I want a user to be logged for 30 days for example.

Thank you